# Passing Components as Props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to come up with a generic function to wrap specific contexts around each given page.
I'm doing this in my routes section, which will wrap around the state need for a page by page basis. Ideally, this would just be a helper function.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Analytics from "./pages/Analytics";

import { HomeProvider } from "./context/Home";


const wrapPageInContext = (Page, Context) => {
  return (
    <Context>
      <Page />
    </Context>
  );
};

const ContextWrappedHome = () => {
  return (
    <HomeProvider>
      <Home />
    </HomeProvider>
  );
};

export const MainRoutes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        // This fails! :( 
        <Route
          exact
          path="/home"
          component={wrapPageInContext(Home, HomeProvider)}
        />
        // This works!! 
        <Route
          exact
          path="/home"
          component={ContextWrappedHome}
        />
        <Route exact path="/Analytics" component={<Analytics />
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: fails in what way?

Comment: Having comments that point out failures without having context, error messages or a description of the error in the code isn't really all that helpful. Can you give a better description of what fails, which error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

your `wrapPageInContext`  function needs to return a component, like so:

```
const wrapPageInContext = (Page, Context) => () => {
  return (
    <Context>
      <Page />
    </Context>
  );
};
```

Or to make this a little more explicit:

```
const wrapPageInContext = (Page, Context) => {
  const Wrapper = () => (
    <Context>
      <Page />
    </Context>
  )
  return Wrapper
};
```

Comment: Correct as it is, it might lack some explanation :)